# Expression-bodied members doesn't create new instances?

Tags: c#, properties, field, referrals, expression-body

I'm curiuous why Expression-bodied properties doesn't create persisant objects.

```cs
public List<string> Pages { get; } = new List<string>();
```

Does create a persistant isntance of `List<string>`, just like always.

But

```cs
public List<string> Pages => new List<string>();
```

Somehow this does craete a new instance, but seems to be volatile.

Even when adding a new string to `Pages` won't add it.

There's no runtime- nor compile-time error, but I think there should be at least a warning.
It took me quite a while to figure it out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

Is a bit odd documented.

Comment: `public List<string> Pages => new List<string>();` is a shortcut for `public List<string> Pages { get { return new List<string>(); } }`

Comment: That totally answers my question, why cannot be ms-docs so precise.

Comment: This is probably a better link for the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#expression-body-definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties noted with `{ get; }` have an internal field that stores the value. However, the second example which is expression-bodied, declares the creation of the list as the getter, which means it will be ran every time you access it, and every time it creates a new list.

As noted in comments, it is the same as `get { return new List<string>(); }`, to explain it in a different way.

To change this behavior, you need to have an internal field which would store the List instance and the expression-bodied member to return it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link in the documentation you linked, we have [read-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties):

> Starting with C# 6, you can use expression body definition to implement a read-only property. To do that, use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> PropertyType PropertyName => expression;
> ```
>
> **The following example defines a Location class whose read-only Name property is implemented as an expression body definition that returns the value of the private locationName field:**
>
> ```
> public class Location
> {
>    private string locationName;
>
>    public Location(string name)
>    {
>       locationName = name;
>    }
>
>    public string Name => locationName;
> }
> ```

(Emphasis mine)

To rephrase it: when you access the `Name` property, the value held by `locationName` is returned. If the value of `locationName` changes, and you access `Name` again, you get the new value of `locationName`.

It's equivalent to:

```cs
public string Name
{
    get => locationName;
}
```

Or

```cs
public string Name
{
    get { return locationName; }
}
```